# Understanding and resolving ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

I'm dealing with an intermittent, hard to reproduce `ConcurrentModificationException` in a chunk of legacy code:

```
class LegacyCode {
    private final WeakHashMap<A, B> mItems = new WeakHashMap<A, B>();

    public void someWork() {
        final List<A> copy = new LinkedList<A>();

        for (final A item : mItems.keySet()) {
            copy.add(item);
        }

        for (final A item : copy) {
            item.someMethod();
        }
    }

    public void addItem(final A item) {
        mItems.put(item, new B());
    }

    public void removeItem(final A item) {
        mItems.remove(item);
    }
}
```

The CME is being thrown in:

```
for (final A item : mItems.keySet()) {
    copy.add(item);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure as to why we create `copy` in this manner. The CME is thrown because either `addItem(A)` or `removeItem(A)` is called while the for-each loop is running.

*Questions*

1. Is my understanding of why CME is being thrown correct?
2. Will I avoid CME if I replace the for-each loop with:

   `final List<A> copy = new LinkedList<A>(mItems.keySet());`
3. Will this change be equivalent to the for-each loop we will be replacing? As far as I can tell, both snippets create a shallow copy of `mItems.keySet()` in `copy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my understanding of why CME is being thrown correct?

Absolutely. This is exactly what is happening.

> Will I avoid CME if I replace the for-each loop with:
>
> ```
> final List<A> copy = new LinkedList<A>(mItems.keySet());
> ```

No, you would not, because constructor of `LinkedList<A>` would have a similar loop. So you are correct in saying that this change will be equivalent to the for-each loop we will be replacing.

As far as fixing this problem is concerned, there is no off-the-shelf concurrent replacement for `WeakHashMap` class in Java standard library. You can address this the obvious way by making `addItem` and `removeItem` synchronized, and adding a synchronized block around the loop constructing a `copy`. You can also look into [third-party collections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29458541/335858) that solve this problem without using `synchronized` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I understand why placing the the for-each loop inside a _synchronized_ block is required. But, what is the reason behind making `addItem` and `removeItem` synchronized?

Comment: @user3264740 You need both reading and writing sides `synchronized`. Otherwise, `foreach` loop would freely acquire the lock, even though `addItem` or `removeItem` may be in progress.